# Will the Kitkat application will run in Lollipop version

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

I'm using Delphi XE7 for developing android application. And for my mobile I'm having Kitkat version and recently got the lollipop version update, but i have not done. And in Delphi Xe7 I'm using the Kitkat version as the base package. Will i face any problem, if i'm updating my mobile Kitkat version to Lollipop version. And also will the application will be running in Lollipop version or not..?

Comment: It seems reasonable that if you target 5.0 then your app won't run on older versions

Comment: See if I'm targeting for version 4.4.4, then will my application  runs on 5.0 or  not..?

Comment: I think it will. But the other way around won't. I think. It's so easy for you to do this yourself with the simulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two (and a half) separate questions here :

> Can I use a 5.0+ (Lollipop) device to develop with?

Yes, but you must apply a [(beta) hotfix](http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/30110) to XE7 to fix a number of known issues using a Lollipop device for development.  Even if you are not using a 5.0 device this is recommended for app compatibility with 5.0 devices.

> Will the application will be running in Lolipop version or not..?

Delphi XE7 only [supports API levels 10->19](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Android_Devices_Supported_for_Application_Development) so your compiled application will not take advantage of any Lollipop-specific (API level 21) features (afaik).  The resulting application should compile to the same thing it did using a KitKat development device.

> Will there be any new bugs?

This is the half-question.  I don't think anyone can answer this with any certainly.  The best answer I can give is "possibly maybe".  Compatibility with Lollipop is in beta - that comes with some uncertainties.

Comment: Hi J,

I'm using Delphi XE7 trail version ( _Note: I have not updated the Hot fix for Android Lolipop_). I have created some  application which consists of some Inage, Grid, EditBox, button, etc.. also I have kept the base version as Level 14. I can able to run this application in KitKat version.

**But  the application is not running in Lolipop version. Application is crashing**

Comment: @Work2Enjoy-Enjoy2Work  I'm not sure why you are telling me this.  If you want advice, install the hotfix.  Otherwise, posting a new question about this crash sounds like the thing to do.